# Understanding Add Event Listener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Please help me understand why scenario #1 fails whereas scenario #2 works. Scenario #2 triggers the "textx" function when I mouse down on the div/id"box" element, not so with scenario #1. I guess the element isn't binding to the event listener, but why? and What's the process? Thank you in advance.

Scenario #1:

```
 <script>

     function testx(e){  

          alert("test 123"); 
     }

     var boxTest = document.getElementById("box");

     boxTest.addEventListener("mousedown", testx, false);
     // Or this: boxTest.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){ testx(e); }, false);

 </script>
```

Scenario #2:

```
 <script>

    function testx(e){  

        alert("test 123"); 

    }

    function setEvent() {

        var boxTest = document.getElementById("box");
        boxTest.addEventListener("mousedown", testx, false);

    }
    window.addEventListener("load", setEvent);

 </script>
```

Comment: for scenario#1, is your script tag defined before you define your div or afterwards ?

Comment: Also if you will check in console,  you will find that for scenario#1, if script tag was executed before div was created, boxTest would be null/undefined

Comment: @RobG - you should make your comment into an answer.

Comment: I see that in scenario #1 "boxTest" is not being assigned the div object. So the problem must be with this assignment. Just an observation. I could still use some reflection. Thanks. P.S. I didn't notice your answers before I commented Thank you for your replies. I'll look through your answers now.

Comment: I tested your answers and the script worked as you said it would. My testing was only to help my understanding of your answers, which were more than logical, So I never doubted them. Much to the contrary I appreciated (like always) your help. I'm thankful that we beginners have such a platform in Stackoverflow to help us learn. Thank you very much. And I would like to thank Stackoverflow the same.

Comment: RobG U ans my Q. Convert your comment & I will check it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue in scenario 1 is most likely because the element doesn't exist when the script runs. In the second case, the script waits until the document is entirely loaded before attempting to add the listener.

To fix that, move the first script element to just before the closing body tag (or at least after the closing tag of the *box* element) and likely it will work.